# Can you get dynamic mapping on some object fields?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have docs of the form:

```
user:
  id: 'X'
  profile: 
    name: 'A B'
    foo: 'a string' or 3
```

I create an index with

```
   "mappings": {
      "users": {
         "properties": {
            "profile": {
               "type": "object",
               "properties": {
                  "foo": {
                     "type": "string"
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
```

to coerce the docs that have `profile.foo` as an int into Strings. When I  ingest docs however, the mapping gets changed to the first doc type, which has a number for `profile.foo`. How do I get it to not override the mapping I set? Is it necessary to specify all properties of the `profile` object?

Comment: It should not override if you have defined the mapping. Please check if the type name is not the issue. You have used "users" in mapping and in the sample doc it is "user"

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what was wrong, but the answer is yes, you can, and my example should have worked, and works now.